# How to test if the param mapping to the custom annotation is correct

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am using a custom annotation to trigger an Aspect. It works fine and all. I have also written individual unit tests for the get and aspect methods.

My question is:
But how can I write the test such that when I call the get method, I am able to test that the obj.someString value did indeed map correctly to the method's param's value?
Assuming I should be writing this test for the aspect and not the get method. Please advice if otherwise.

The get method and aspect as follows. Note that they are in separate classes and packages:

```
@CustomAnnot(name = "ABC", keys = "#obj.someString")
public OffersResponse get(CustomObject obj, List<String> list) {
    //
}


@Around("@annotation(customAnnot)")
public Object aspect(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, CustomAnnot customAnnot) throws Throwable {
    //
}
```